# How to modify this query to be executed?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query that I want it to show "Not Yet" instead of showing NULL values for the Status column from the database. **How to do that?**

```
SELECT     dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Title, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Description, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username, dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus.Status,
                 CASE WHEN dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus.Status  IS NULL THEN 'NOT YET'
FROM         dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog INNER JOIN
                      dbo.employee ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username = dbo.employee.Username LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.StatusID = dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus.ID
WHERE     (dbo.employee.Username = @Username)
```

For your information, that database design is as following:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name
SafetySuggestionsLog Table: ID, Title, Description, Username, StatusID
SafetySuggestionsStatus: ID, Status
```

Comment: Did you check the syntax of the CASE WHEN clause?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `COALESCE` is better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) or [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933210%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

```
SELECT     dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Title, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Description, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username, COALESCE(dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus.Status, "Not Yet") as 'Status'
FROM         dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog INNER JOIN
                      dbo.employee ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username = dbo.employee.Username LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.StatusID = dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus.ID
WHERE     (dbo.employee.Username = @Username)
```

OR

```
SELECT     dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Title, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Description, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username, ISNULL(dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus.Status, "Not Yet") as 'Status'
FROM         dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog INNER JOIN
                      dbo.employee ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username = dbo.employee.Username LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.StatusID = dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus.ID
WHERE     (dbo.employee.Username = @Username)
```

Comment: And remove the malformed CASE WHEN which prevents the query from compiling

Comment: You are assuming an `ELSE Status END` that their code does not contain. (Probably a correct assumption though)

Comment: Just in case anyone wants to know the difference between ISNULL and COALESCE, COALESCE returns the first non-null from the args passed to it, whereas ISNULL returns the original value or the replacement if NULL

Comment: @ypercube - No they are not always equivalent for 2 parameters. `DECLARE @X CHAR(1);SELECT ISNULL(@X, 'Foo'),COALESCE(@X, 'Foo');` returns `(F,Foo)`

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty much right there, you can use ISNULL or CASE

```
CASE WHEN dbo.Blah.Status IS NULL THEN 'Not Yet' ELSE dbo.Blah.Status END
```

or

```
isnull(dbo.Blah.Status, 'Not Yet')
```